# Install fails with error create: failed to create: Secret "sh.helm.release.v1.<release>.v1" is invalid:data:Too long:must have at most 1048576 bytes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helmfile, helm3

I have multiple sub-charts under a single composite/umbrella chart.
What could be the possible reasons for this error?  Are there constraints with the sizes of a particular yaml? What should at most have 1048576 bytes? What can be the possible solutions so that more charts can be added to the composite/umbrella chart?

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can try to reproduce it and understand what can be wrong.

Comment: You tagged this question with "helmfile"; [that tool](https://github.com/helmfile/helmfile) manages multiple Helm releases outside an umbrella-chart framework, and might avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Secrets are limited to 1MiB in size as described here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#restrictions

What are you trying to encode into a secret that makes it >1MiB?

Comment: the mentioned secret is created by helm and stores the information about release. Since the umbrella chart had a lot of sub-charts , the secret had to store a lot of information which exceeded 1MiB. 
A solution for this was to remove unnecessary files from the sub-charts so that the secret will parse less files than actual.
To decode the secret , refer : https://gist.github.com/DzeryCZ/c4adf39d4a1a99ae6e594a183628eaee
This mentions the list of files it parses and stores information about.

Comment: If you have a ton of subcharts, a rearchitecture might be worth considering. One or two subcharts are understable. How many subcharts are talking about that causes the >1MB secret? I also see you're using Wordpress. I used Bitnami's Wordpress in my cluster, and that only references three dependent charts: `mariadb`, `Memcached` and their `common` chart. And still doesn't trip the 1MB limit